# Sistema de menções igual Twitter e Facebook

Tags: php

Olá,

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de menções igual o Twitter e Facebook, quando o usuário fizer um post, tudo que vir depois do @ será armazenado na tabela "notificações".

```
preg_match_all("/\B@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/i", $comment, $mentions);
$mentions = array_map(function($str){ return substr($str, 1); },           $mentions[0]);
foreach($mentions as $mentionedUser){
if(!valid_username($mentionedUser)){ continue; }
// aqui ficará a tabela de inserir notificações
}
```

Porém o que eu estou enfrentando dificuldade seria na hora de exibir no post já criado as menções.

No caso eu pensei em fazer assim:

```
$post = preg_replace('/(^|[^a-z0-9_])@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '$1<a         href="http://www.meusite.com/$2">@$2</a>', $post);
```

Porém, como eu faço pra verificar se realmente o usuário existe pra então ele executar esse preg_replace? Qualquer sugestão será bem-vinda.

Comment: Segue esse exemplo de como seria, e veja se é isso que você quer. http://ideone.com/ZGoibT

Comment: Mauro, no caso só pra eu entender, ele verifica pelo $result é isso?

Comment: Sim, o result vai retornar um array com todos os usuários, dai você faz um laço de repetição, verifica de um por um se existe e retorna apenas os que retornarem true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pega os dados através da expressão regular:

```
$texto = '@Felipe @luizao @Patronaltacao abobrinha @hashtag @ textoxyz @NomeAqui';

preg_match_all('/(^|\s)(@\w+)/', $texto, $result);

$data = $result[2];

$data = array_map(function($value) { 
          return array('possible_account_mail' => strtolower(str_replace('@', '', $value)).'@',
                       'parameter_send' => $value,
                       'account_name' => str_replace('@', '', $value),
                       ); 
    }, $data);

preg_replace(,)
print_r($data);
```

E depois faz uma consulta no banco através da conta do usuário:

```
 $conta = $data[0]['possible_account_mail'];
 "SELECT * from tabela where email LIKE '%$conta%'";
```

Para fazer isso, obviamente você vai ter que saber trabalhar bem com ajax. Agora a ideia é substituir a string quando encontrar o registro... você pode implementar isso usando a bibliteca UI de autocomplete:

```
$('#input').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("/path/request/", function (data) {
            response($.map(data.dealers, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value,
                    value: key
                };
            }));
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
});
```

[**Documentação**](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

> Aqui tem um exemplo de como utilizar, a substituição através de um método:

```
<?php
function replaceAccountExists($accounts_request, $texto) {
    preg_match_all('/(^|\s)(@\w+)/', $texto, $result);
    $data = $result[2];
    $data = array_map(function($value) use ($accounts_request) { 
    $account = strtolower(str_replace('@', '', $value));
    $exists = (in_array($account,$accounts_request));
        return array(
                 'parameter_send' => $value,
                 'exists_account'=> $exists,
                 'url' => '<a href="http://www.meusite.com/' 
                          . $account . '">'
                          . $value . '</a>'
        ); 
    }, $data);

    if (!empty($data)) {
       foreach($data as $val) {
           if ($val['exists_account']) {
              $texto = str_replace($val['parameter_send'],$val['url'], $texto);
           }
       }
    }
    return $texto;
   }

   //requisições válidas do banco
   $accounts_request = array(
    'existo',
    'existia',
    'hash2tag'
   );

    $texto = '@Felipe @luizao @Patronaltacao abobrinha @existo @hash2tag @ textoxyz @NomeAqui @existia';
    $texto_novo = replaceAccountExists($accounts_request, $texto); 
    echo $texto_novo;
```

Veja no [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/0KLsHs)

Comment: Ivan Ferrer, então, a minha dúvida é a seguinte, no caso vamos supor que a postagem seria o $texto, ai depois ele faz um preg_match_all né e busca aonde tem as tags, certo, ai depois ele separa em arrays, e ai depois eu faço a consulta pra buscar na tabela, mas e depois como eu faço pra mostrar como link somente as existentes, que essa é a minha dúvida inicial.

Comment: @ViniciusHenzel, editei a pergunta, para você ver como fazer.

Comment: Nossa @IvanFerrer muito bom, muito obrigado mesmo, salvou minha vida!!!!!